# How to get details of user id from multiple column conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel

I have a users table, i need to retrieve address,phone and email of a user where columns having address_type = 1, phone_type=1,email_type=1. ('_type=1' means present user using details and others are unused and archived records)

Below is my table structure

[image: user table]

From above table i want  to get **address,phone,email** of user_id=1 and where conditions are address_type=1, phone_type=1,email_type=1

Any help would be great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eloquent for that. Load the data with one simple query:

```
$data = Model::where('user_id', $userId)->get();
```

And then get an address, a phone number and an email from this collection:

```
$address = $data->where('address_type', 1)->first()->address;
$phone = $data->where('phone_type', 1)->first()->phone;
$email = $data->where('email_type', 1)->first()->email;
```

Comment: Thank you. But it requires 3 diff set of queries to be processed, can we make it one go ?

Comment: @Guru it makes just one query. Three lines you see after that is just working with the collection.

Comment: Hi, Is there a way instead of one user ,if we need to display all users data at shot without foreach calling on eloquent model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when address_type = 1 then address end) as address,
       max(case when phone_type = 1 then phone end) as phone,
       max(case when email_type = 1 then email end) as email
from t
where id = 1
group by id;
```

If there can be multiple values with "1", then use `group_concat()` instead of `max()` to get all of them.

Comment: Hi , I tried with both max and group_concat. Its showing one record with address_type as 1 and not not showing phone and email..

Comment: @Guru . . . Are you sure the conditions are the same as in this answer?

Comment: Yes the conditions are same as to retrieve values based on Boolean condition for the column.   This is a cart system, where users will update address,phone,email etc, which ever he updates latest, the particular row will be set boolean 1 condition and i need to retrieve the record of it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing  conditional aggregation model, i dont knew this before. Happy to know on it.

Comment: @Guru . . . If that is the process, this logic should be working.

Answer (score 0):

I got the below solution by making query in column selection itself as below

SELECT DISTINCT user_id,
     (SELECT address from tsets where address_type IN (1)) as address,
     (SELECT email from tsets where email_type IN (1)) as email 
FROM `tsets`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following query:

```
$user = Model::where('user_id', $userId)
    ->where('address_type', 1)
    ->where('phone_type', 1)
    ->where('email_type', 1)
    ->first();
```

Note: replace **Model** with the name of your model.

More info about Eloquent: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models

Comment: Yea but this works when a single user_id row have all '1' for address,phone etc.     Here the problem is the boolean "1" can be in multiple rows, say row 3 for user id 1 has address_type 1, row4 for user_id 1 has phone_type 1.. How to solve this

Comment: Snapshot in the question description helps to analyse well on the boolean condition.

Comment: So you mean an OR instead of an AND condition?